# quitar borde borde azul al seleccionar un campo de un formulario

Tags: css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo unas dudas como hago para quitarle el borde azul cuando seleccionas un campo del formulario,  intente con 
`input::placeholder{
 border:none;
}`

pero eso no quito el border azul al hacer selección

CODIGO DEL FORMULARIO

```
<div class="contenedor-form">
    <form class="Form-corp" action="#" method="POST">
        <label class="label-form" for="NM">Nombre</label>

        <input placeholder="NOMBRE" type="text" name="nombre" id="NM" class="input-form" required>

        <label class="label-form" for="AP">Apellido</label>

        <input placeholder="APELLIDO" type="text" name="apellido" id="AP" class="input-form" required>

        <label class="label-form" for="CM">Comentario</label>

        <input placeholder="COMENTARIO" class="input-form" type="text" name="comentario" id="CM" required>

        <input class="input-send" type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">        


    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Podrías indicar el css de label-form y de Form-corp quizás ahí indiques el borde

Comment: gracias por la solución me sirvió, hasta ahora no había encontrado nada